# Raspberry 3B+ freezes when using two webcams

Tags: pi-3, webcam

I attached 2 webcams and capture images once in few minutes using fswebcam. No problems. (Some generic 2K webcam and a Microsoft LifeCam HD 3000)

However, the RaPi froze "in production" approx after 12hrs. Now, on my test bench I managed to reproduce it. It seems that it works with one webcam but once I plug the Microsoft camera, things get hairy. I managed to freeze it this morning, the camera was ON and no picture was saved.

Now I am running it with only MS camera, see if it blocks.

I did not start the watchdog.

Could it be a power issue?

**LE**

After some more testing (see comments) I realized that is the SD card. Very weird indeed. The bug surfaces (quite reproducible) if I write the pictures on a "free" card. If I let the system accumulate several MB of pictures, no more freezing (It run with 2 cameras for 6 days). As soon as I deleted the pictures and re-run the script, it lasted ~24 hrs. I did it 2 times just to be sure.

Good news is that the watchdog detects the halting and reboots the Raspberry.

Here is a nice video about the adventure: https://odysee.com/@ml-visoft:d/03_rapi_sd_card_fail:d

Comment: What power supply? How much memory used? What is CPU usage?

Comment: sounds like a classic memory leak

Comment: @CoderMike It has the Raspberry logo on it. Sth around 2 amps. But it is plugged in, don't want to unplug it (Test running with only Microsoft camera attached). CPU usage is 0.96, 0.53, 0.54 (reported by htop). Besides the python processes that take pictures, there is htop started and a tail -f to a log. 88.3M/924M so no worries there.

Comment: Later I will log the mem+cpu (have to google it to see how) but I doubt that is some memory leak related to taking photos. The codebase is ripped from a larger home automation suite that works without issues (~400+ days uptime last time I checked)

Comment: 9 days with one camera, no hiccups. Now I connected 2 cameras, let's see what will happen.

Comment: 6 days with 2 cameras, same soft, same everything. I didn't even reboot when inserting 2nd camera. Pictures were taken, no glitches whatsoever. The USB power is rated at 2.5A. I rebooted (had to check the amperage on the power supply), I am going to delete all pictures and then put smaller delay between pictures. See if the problem was in fact the SD card and not the PSU.

Comment: Ok, freeze achieved! So the only thing I did is deleting previous pictures. So SD 90%? I will try to reproduce couple of times noted how many pictures it took.